# I need help with a probability problem that involves drawing things at random and without replacement.

Tags: probability

This is the question.
Kevin plays a game in which he draws 3 cards at random and without replacement from a set of 7 cards numbered with the integers 1 through 7. He wins if the sum of the three numbers of the drawn cards is at least 10 or if 5 is one of the drawn cards. What is the probability of winning?

I already found the probability of drawing 5, which is 3/7. However, I'm stuck on the other case for 10. I could find all scenarios, but that would take quite a while and I want to know if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: There aren't many bad outcomes. After all, $2+3+4=9$ so, other than that one case all the other bad rolls must involve $1$.

Comment: So I can use complimentary counting. Never thought about that!

Comment: Right, definitely the way to go here.

Comment: To be fair, that is still a bit brute force-ish.  One can recognize that the average sum will be $3\times 3.5 = 10.5$ and $10$ is frustratingly close to that average.  One can reason that the probability of getting $11$ or more should be the same as getting the probability of $10$ or less by symmetry, so letting $X$ be the sum of the cards it could be easier to find by $Pr(X\geq 10)=Pr(X=10)+Pr(X\geq 11)=Pr(X=10)+\frac{1}{2}$.  Finding $Pr(X=10)$ can be done also by brute force, or generating functions

Comment: Something to keep in mind for finishing the problem however is going to be that we will be eventually applying inclusion-exclusion in some regard to combine the results of being greater than 10 and containing a five.  For this, I suggest noting $Pr(A\cup B) = Pr(A\cap B^c)+Pr(B)$ rather than where people's minds usually go first which is $Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B)$.  Letting $A$ be "contains a five" and $B$ be "has sum 10 or greater", you have $Pr(A\cap B^c)$ the probability you contain a five and have a sum 9 or less is relatively tame.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom 73=35$ ways to draw three distinct numbers.  Of these, only $$123,124,125,126,134,135,234$$ sum to $<10$.

We note that two of these contain $5$.

It follows that there are only $5$ bad outcomes (namely $123,124,126,134,234$) out of the possible $35$.  Thus the probability of winning is $$\frac {30}{35}=\boxed {\frac 67}$$

Comment: It does.  The $35-7=28$ rolls which sum to at least $10$ are all good.  Then I enumerated those with smaller sum and added the two which contain a $5$ to the "good list".  That makes a total of $30$ good outcomes.

Comment: Thanks so much :)

Comment: As with any argument by enumeration, I suggest checking.  Make sure I listed all the bad cases.  I did it quickly and might have left off one or two.

Comment: I did double check it and I got the same answer.

Comment: @AryanHarkawat Then I would recommend you to accept the answer.